# How to prevent caching in Google Chrome with meta tags

Tags: google-chrome, caching, browser-cache, meta-tags

Is it possible to prevent caching files in Google Chrome programmatically?

I'd like to achieve the same effect as the option "disable cache" in chrome developer tools.

Main problem is that I'm using external script (it can't be changed by me) which loads another script - putting additional (randomly generated) parameters into source url for that script won't help.

So far I've tried to use meta tags:

```
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-store" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1990 12:00:00 GMT" />
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
```

After testing with different combinations of that tags I can only say that Google Chrome ignores that at all.

Is there any option to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to use the HTTP response headers, instead of HTML meta tags: see [Disabling browser caching for all browsers from ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/914027/disabling-browser-caching-for-all-browsers-from-asp-net).

If you're asking about disabling the caching of data in input elements, see [How to prevent google chrome from caching my inputs, esp hidden ones when user click back?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2629593/how-to-prevent-google-chrome-from-caching-my-inputs-esp-hidden-ones-when-user-c)