# ASP.NET - DropDownList contains wrong value upon Browser-Back-Button

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have this DropDownList inside a DataList.

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="DDL_ProdCat" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DDL_ProdCat_SelectedIndexChanged" 
                  Autopostback="true" DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="ID" />
```

When the user makes a selection in this DropDownList, for some selections, they are redirected to a separate page.

After being redirected, the user hits their browser-back button, they are returned to this page with the DropDownList.

Unfortunately, the selection which redirected them to the new page is still selected.

**Example**

- DDL contains A,B -- Initial Selected Value: A
- User selects B -- Postback redirects them to another page
- User hits "back" on browser
- The page now shows "B" as being selected while the page-state suggests that "A" should still be selected. The page can never be in the "B" state, because "B" is marked to redirect users to that other page.

Is there a way to reset the DropDownList selection to a particular value when the user revisits the page via the browser-back button?

**Note**

- I am forced to use a DDL here, because the common-case is that a redirect does not occur. I understand it is generally not the best option for linking users to other pages.
- Unfortunately, I am unable to turn off browser-caching for the entire page for performance reasons

Comment: Perhaps a client-side script to reset the DDL selections upon arrival via the back-button?

Answer (score 4):

If it is OK to remove page-level browser-caching, you can try to remove the cache so that it reloads the page when the user goes back. Add this to page load:

```
Response.Expires = 0
Response.Cache.SetNoStore()
Response.AppendHeader("Pragma", "no-cache")
```

Comment: Oh, didn't notice that you couldn't turn off caching. Disregard then.

Comment: What's the difference between this and Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache)?

Comment: Thanks for the advice Paul, I was not clear in my initial question regarding page-level caching

Comment: @James, Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache) only works for IE I believe. [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/914027/disabling-browser-caching-for-all-browsers-from-asp-net)

Comment: @hamlin11 you could have a session boolean in your 2nd page that's set to true and if user goes back to 1st page have that boolean used in if statement to deselect ddl.

Comment: Paul, unfortunately the page-init and page-load functions are not hit upon browser-back button on the original page. Now, if I could cause a postback to occur, then I'm in my comfort zone. However, I just checked w/ breakpoints -- page load & page init not hit upon postback. I like the idea, but it might need to be accomplished upon browser-back w/ jquery

Answer (score 0):

As suggested, use JavaScript on the page to re-set the selection in the drop down.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code that worked for me:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.onload = function () {
    var ControlValue = document.getElementById("<%= DropDownList.ClientID %>");
    if (ControlValue.value != origControlValue) {
      ControlValue.value = origControlValue;
    }
  }
  var origControlValue = document
    .getElementById("<%= DropDownList.ClientID %>").value;
</script>
```