# Avoid browser cache in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, browser

I try to disable the html url browser cache using programmatically.
 I am developing as a site using asp.net, I need to disable the html url browser for the security reason.
 I tried many ways to disable the cache but none seems to work. Any ideas?

```
<iframe id="iframe" src="http://www.phy.mtu.edu/basiccomputing/sample.html" runat ="server" width="200" height="300"></iframe>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/918346/284240

Answer (score 1):

As far as it's a html file you want to work with, a easy solution is to append a random number and the end of your url like this

```
<iframe id="iframe" src="http://www.phy.mtu.edu/basiccomputing/sample.html?12345" runat ="server" width="200" height="300"></iframe>
```

I don't know wich view engine you are using, so i cant provide a sample you simple copy and paste.

**You have to replace `?12345`with a random number like `new Random().Next().ToString()`**

If you call a asp.net page you can control it with

```
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(System.Web.HttpCacheability.NoCache);
Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
```

more informations about that:

[ASP.NET Cache Examples](http://www.dotnetperls.com/cache)

**hope this helps**

Answer (score 0):

You could attach a random parameter to the URL so the browser thinks it's a different page every time.

```
http://www.phy.mtu.edu/basiccomputing/sample.html?rand=[INSERT RANDOM HERE]
```

Answer (score 0):

try

`HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-1))`. [This site](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/NoCaching.aspx) has something that can be quite helpful.