# Is it possible to disable off-line caching for Firefox in ASP.NET (at the server level)?

Tags: asp.net, firefox, offline-caching

How do I disable offline caching for firefox in ASP.NET or in IIS? I found this post:

[Disabling browser caching for all browsers from ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/914027/disabling-browser-caching-for-all-browsers-from-asp-net)

This doesn't address the issue completely. It just disables caching from the back button (when not in off-line mode).

Here is a simple scenario:

If user A logs on to his bank. User A is doing transactions and he even goes to update some personal data. Finally user A is done and logs off from his bank website. User A leaves the browser on, because he has another tab open downloading a file that is a few gigs. User B would like to go on to his email to send out some emails, so user A doesn't close the browser. He knows the security risks, because he has read what must be done once you log off of the site, but he doesn't want to stop the download. For user A, to have to redownload is too much time for him and well he is just your typical user and doesn't think user B (being a good friend of his) will do anything malicious.  So then user B uses the browser. The first thing user B does is "work offline". User B now has all data from user A. The page has an off-line cache for user B to see. User B is now able to open the history to view those cached pages, or just simply click back if the page was left open (either way works). User B now has all the pages that user A has browsed to. So any sensitive data is now his.

Does anyone know if this is possible to control at the server level. I know in firefox you go to about:config, but that is not an option for the server to tweak. Even so this can be told to the user, but not every user is going to be able to do this (being too complicated for some users) or some users will just ignore the warnings out of laziness or just not reading what the page says. I know there will be that one person that will say, "oh well that's their own fault and they deserve that". I honestly think ignorance in this sense is not the user's fault. Consider an older person in their 80s who is not technology-centric (like my father who I constantly give him the do's and don't's about online, but he still doesn't really understand the risks completely).

So I reiterate again, is it possible to disable this kind of off-line caching at the server level? I also found this post:

http://forums.asp.net/post/1386380.aspx

Would this help at all? Any help please. Please be constructive and not start a debate. I think I have been very clear, and I have done a lot of research on this with no luck. Please note that only the off-line caching on firefox is what is giving the problem, on every other browser (or on firefox onlinle) the caching has been disabled as expected.

**Update:**

I actually already have what the last link suggests (http://forums.asp.net/post/1386380.aspx) and it still doesn't prevent the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Disabling cache from server side is kind of impossible because server can only request the browser to not store in cache. Rest is up to the browser to follow it or not.

The best option is not to send the data to browser , so it is never cached, instead fetch it on demand using json/Xml or any thing you are comfortable with.

The only trick that worked for me was to remove all sensitive information from loading via regular page methods, and load it via ajax/jquery on window.ready event.  Once I implemented callback and ajax the back button and 'work offline' problem got solved but rolling out that with ajax callback was really a big task.

Comment: I had considered doing this, but never tried it. So did it work? Was your security team able to not do a session replay attack?

Comment: yes got it pretty secure, though having a penetration testing is beyond the scope of our budget