# iPhone 5 Splash Screen - Can't delete

Tags: iphone, ios, mobile-website

Making a nice mobile site with jQuery.

The splash screen works great except on an iPhone 5 with iOS6 where it continues to show the old screen from day 1 despite that image not even being on the server and clearing cache endless time, and certainly deleting the app storied on the phone desktop.

... so where is that thing stored on the phone? if not in the cache?

Answer (score 0):

Try [this link](http://browsers.about.com/od/allaboutwebbrowsers/ss/iphonecache.htm), it worked for me on my iPhone.

Here are the steps:

- Go to Settings
- Select 'Safari'
- Hit 'Clear Cache'

EDIT: I just saw the comment that you tried to clear the cache. Did you do it this way?

**Are you using PHP?**

Add the following code to your site, it will send a [header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) which prevents the browser from caching your site.

```
header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 12012 05:00:00 GMT");
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
```

**Are you using ASP.NET?**

Check out this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/914027/disabling-browser-caching-for-all-browsers-from-asp-net) to learn about preventing the browser to cache your site.

Comment: Thank you dandan78 but yep, cleared that cache many times.

We're using PHP and I will look into this (but we're storing variables so we'll see if that's doable.)