# Where to set no-cache header - in pageload or page init (in .net)

Tags: asp.net, header, browser-cache

I have web page that uses no-cache mechanism for not to let browser to cache content. However, I have some doubts. The developer has inserted no cache code into the PageLoad method in MasterPage.

It is like this (**on Page Load in Master Page**)

```
   HttpContext.Current.Response.CacheControl = "no-cache"
   HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Pragma", "no-cache")
   HttpContext.Current.Response.ExpiresAbsolute = DateTime.Now.Date
   HttpContext.Current.Response.Expires = -1
```

I have some doubt that this is the correct action and whether this could should be better inserted into `BasePage OnInit` event?

Comment: Its not a problem, as long as you add it before generating Response it is ok

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this HTTPHeaders before you generate the response. [Check MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a6s4ks5w%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

`Page_init/page_load`  or `MasterPage/BasePage/ActualPage`

Refer [Disabling browser caching for all browsers from ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/914027/disabling-browser-caching-for-all-browsers-from-asp-net)

Also you could do this in page directive

```
<%@ OutputCache Duration="60" VaryByParam="None"%>
```

Even in Web.config you can configure

```
<caching>
  <outputCacheSettings>
    <outputCacheProfiles>
      <add name="Cache30Seconds" duration="30" 
        varyByParam="none" />
    </outputCacheProfiles>
  </outputCacheSettings>
</caching>
```

[More Information on Caching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcacheability.aspx)