# Clearing cache on Master.Page

Tags: asp.net, caching

I have a master page and there is  ahref link on this masterpage. It is linked to page2.aspx When user login, he/she goes to default.aspx directly. When user clicks that link, the page goes to page2.aspx.  The problem is that I want to clear cache of default page. This way when user clicks to link after login, he/she won't be able to go back to default page using back button on browser. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to simply clear a page that is already in cache. Instead, you need to prevent the page from being cached by the browser:

[Disabling browser caching for all browsers from ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/914027/disabling-browser-caching-for-all-browsers-from-asp-net)