# How to restrict storage of files in browser temporary directory?

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to insert records into database through asp.net web form and am also maintaing logs like how many records inserted, how many records rejected and also maintaing rejection reason in for each record. I am writing all these statistics to a TXT file say Logs.txt which stores in the server.

I am displaying stored log file Logs.txt to user on the browser like
http://mywebsite.com/logs/Logs.txt

Log file is displaying properly in the browser but same file getting stored in temporary location (Windows/TempporaryInternetfiles) of a browser. My tester has raised defect as sensitive data gets storing in temporary location.

Now i want to restrict storage of log file in broswer temporary location.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disabling browser caching for all browsers from ASP.NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/914027/disabling-browser-caching-for-all-browsers-from-asp-net)

Comment: IE (and possibly other browsers) will not cache pages accessed over HTTPS.

Comment: Please share what you have tried. Try using the search.