# Program an event to clear client browser cache with Javascript or ASP

Tags: javascript, html, caching, asp-classic, browser-cache

We have this problem that we need to tell our clients to clear their cache every time we have an update to our website.

Is it possible to clear our client`s cache through an event like clicking a button from Admin portal using Javascript or classic ASP?

P.S. I want to do this without disabling browser caching

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disabling browser caching for all browsers from ASP.NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/914027/disabling-browser-caching-for-all-browsers-from-asp-net)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's not possible to clear client browser cache from Backend side. I suggest you add a version param for each static resource url when we deploy a new release. It will make the browser to load new ones. Ex:

```
Resource: http://abc.xyz/static/xx.js?...&version=1.0.xx
```

Comment: This would mean that I`ll need to change the versions every update. This would create problems like version tracking for each files and a pain if you have lots of js files. Any suggestion on how to deal with those?

Comment: No, the trick is to append a parameter/string to the file name in the script tag. We don't need to store tracking version for each file. :)
Example:
<script src="myfile.js?version=${version}"></script>