# always need to disable\delete cache in google chrome

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome, caching

I'm developing a web application, server with ASP.NET and frontend in AngularJS, and every time that I'm deploying a new version, on Azure App Service (IIS as a service) I have a caching problem - the view does not update to the new version until I power on the Disable cache checkbox in the chrome developer tools or press Ctrl+Shift+R

I try to add in the index.html this meta-tags

```
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"/>
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT" />
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
```

but it doesn't work.
I tried a lot of ideas that I found on the network but the issue doesn't solved

Comment: Is the html or javascript caching?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an IIS configuration for static content to set the cache mode and expiry:

```
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
      <staticContent>
         <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseExpires"
            httpExpires="Tue, 19 Jan 2038 03:14:07 GMT" />
      </staticContent>
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Then, if you will check requests to the server to get `JS` and `HTML` files, will appear few headers:

Response:

- **ETag** key for cache entry
- **Last-Modified** last modified date of this file

Request:

- **If-Modified-Since** last modified date of this file - bring the file from the server if the file's last modified date is different from the specified
- **If-None-Match** ETag of cache key - if the last modified date does not differ from the specified, bring file from this cache key

Answer (score 0):

I think this has been asked before (or simmilar), source : [Disabling browser caching for all browsers from ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/914027/disabling-browser-caching-for-all-browsers-from-asp-net)

A solution from this thread which I have found to work for me is to add this to your page header:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    window.onbeforeunload = function () {   
    // This function does nothing.  It won't spawn a confirmation dialog   
    // But it will ensure that the page is not cached by the browser.
}
```