# IE8(+win7) can't download a file which contains no-cache in HTTP header

Tags: internet-explorer-8, download

I found that specific client(`win7 + IE8`) can't download a file(PDF file)

which contains **Cache-Control:no-cache** in HTTP header;

http://www.doosan.com/doosaniv/download.do?path=product&sav=225806754671.pdf&ori=d70s-5_plus.pdf&dir=20110630

[image]

But if the header contains **Cache-Control:no-cache="set-cookie**, there's no problem to download.

http://www.doosan.com/doosaniv/download.do?path=product&sav=225515770296.pdf&ori=d18s-5.pdf&dir=20110630

[image]

And.. in the first situation, If I run IE8 as Administrator, got no problem to download..
(Note that I logon as Administrator in win7. It's weird..)

[I fount a blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2009/10/03/internet-explorer-cannot-download-over-https-when-no-cache.aspx) and it says SSL and no-cache. I think it's similar but different problem.

Thank you.

Comment: [This question][1] covers the same topic.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3415370/

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for posting this question. The links and examples were very helpful in solving other problems.

From the MSDN article you link to:
"if a user tries to download* a file over a HTTPS connection, any response headers that prevent caching will cause the file download process to fail."

I'm guessing that IE8 doesn't respect Cache-Control:no-cache="set-cookie" as a proper header, and thus believes there is nothing preventing cache and the download is allowed to continue.