# Unable to download ... from localhost. Unable to open this Internet site. The requested site is either unavailable or cannot be found

Tags: http, internet-explorer-6, explorer

I'm trying to make a default error page for each important http error by adding the following to the web.xml file;

```
<error-page>
  <exception-type>java.sql.SQLException</exception-type>
  <location>/error-mantenimiento.xhtml</location>
 </error-page>
 <error-page>
  <error-code>401</error-code>
  <location>/error-mantenimiento.xhtml</location>
 </error-page>
 <error-page>
  <error-code>403</error-code>
  <location>/error-mantenimiento.xhtml</location>
 </error-page>
 <error-page>
  <error-code>404</error-code>
  <location>/error-mantenimiento.xhtml</location>
 </error-page>
 <error-page>
  <error-code>500</error-code>
  <location>/error-mantenimiento.xhtml</location>
 </error-page>
 <error-page>
  <error-code>503</error-code>
  <location>/error-mantenimiento.xhtml</location>
 </error-page>
```

It does work on firefox or chrome when I try using a fake url, by throwing http 404 error. But on IE6 thru IE8 I get "Unable to download ... from localhost. Unable to open this Internet site. The requested site is either unavailable or cannot be found. Please try again later."

I search this error on the internet, and some people report to have fixed it by enabling or disabling "Do not save encrypted pages to disk" on the security tab. Y try this option enabled and disabled and it keep throwing same error. 
  Also I tried be adding or removing http header tags

as they do on other posts but I get the same IE6 error. The error page does work on IE9 and above.

The web server I use is JBOSS 4.0.3.

As far as I know they dont want to switch browser, and this issue will remain open.

Also we tried by modifying the following records on the windows registry

```
BypassHTTPNoCacheCheck   doubleword   0x00000001
BypassSSLNoCacheCheck    doubleword   0x00000001
```

But didnt work... :S
Any clues on this?

Regardsss

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same issue and stumbled across your question. After researching it a bit further though I was able to find this question as well: [IE : Unable to download * from *. Unable to open this Internet site. The requested site is either unavailable or cannot be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3415370/ie-unable-to-download-from-unable-to-open-this-internet-site-the-request)

If you are running your website over SSL then try setting the header content for the following properties:
Cache-Control: private
Pragma: token

I believe you can set this in xml using the following in your web.xml file:

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>Cache-Control</param-name>
    <param-value>max-age=172801, private</param-value>
</init-param>
<init-param>
    <param-name>Pragma</param-name>
    <param-value>token</param-value>
</init-param>
```

Though I am not terribly familiar with JBOSS. I hope this helps.