# How can I make that php webpages expire in certain time

Tags: php, security, header, browser-cache

For security reasons, several articles recommend "do not cache pages". So I usually put the following at the beginning of my web pages

```
header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
```

That works very well, but many of the visitors likes to use the history buttons. So, I need to allow it for a short period.
I tried to use the following headers

```
header("Cache-Control: maxage=".$expires.", must-revalidate");
header('Expires: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', time()+$expires) . ' GMT');
```

where *$expires* is the time I need. The problem is that pages do not expire, as if those headers were not there. How can I solve this?

Comment: please try this [session timeout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/520237/how-do-i-expire-a-php-session-after-30-minutes)

Comment: Thanks maxjackie. I am already using session timeout, but my intention is to have a little browser-cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short: Browser history caching is something different that you can not entirely control. There is a perfect and exhaustive answer to another question, that also answers your question over here:

[Why both no-cache and no-store should be used in HTTP response?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/866822/why-both-no-cache-and-no-store-should-be-used-in-http-response)