# Symfony2 reverse proxy - separating the caching of the same URL based on a cookie or other setting

Tags: caching, symfony

I'm using the default Symfony2 reverse proxy, and I need to separate caching of the same URL based on a cookie setting.

The site allows for a 'basic' site view by scaling down images and removing JavaScript. As the content is the same I have used the same URL, but of course caching is an issue.

I need to be able to cache them separately (or just ensure the cache is cleared).

I have tried changing the Vary header which normally I have set to:

```
Vary: Accept-Encoding
```

..and have set it to either:

```
Vary: Accept-Encoding, basic
```

..or:

```
Vary: Accept-Encoding, normal
```

That actually works brilliant in Chrome on my Mac, but Safari ignores it. I stopped checking other browsers at this point.

What's the best way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vary: Accept-Encoding tells the client or your reverse proxy to seperate caching of the url for different encodings. ( i.e. with/without gzip).

This is especially useful if you have older browsers not supporting gzip being served the page without gzip and for newer browsers with gzip ... so your reverse proxy will cache both variants of the same url. Without this setting your reverse proxy might end up serving gzipped content to browsers not supporting it... giving unwanted results.

What you are looking for is probably the [ETag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag) header which is kind of like a "cookie" for caching.

The client will send the etag of his cached version and you can then choose from your application wether the client's cached version is valid or not.

```
$response = new Response();
$response->setETag(md5('some_identifier'));
if( $response->isNotModified($this->get('request')) )
{
    // automatically returns null content response with http 304 ( not modified ) header
    return $response; 
}
else
{
    // .. otherwise return a new response, possibly with a different ETag

    // $reponse->setEtag(md5('another_identifier'));
    return  $this->renderView('MyBundle:Main:index.html.twig', array(), $response);
}
```

inspired by [this](http://tracehello.wordpress.com/2011/05/19/symfony2-http-cache-part3-etags/) blogpost.