# How to properly redirect in Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony, redirect

I have a route that creates several database entries. After the creation I'd like to forward to a route that fetches those entries and displays them.

This is the route for fetching/displaying:

```
/**
 * @Route("/admin/app", name="appTourOverview")
 */
public function appTourOverviewAction(Request $request)
{

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    /* Get Network for User */
    $network = $this->getUser()->getNetwork();

    $tours = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Tour')->toursTodayByNetwork($network);

    return $this->render(':app:index.html.twig', array(
        'tour' => $tours,
        'imagePath' => Constants::IMAGE_PATH_DEV,
        'imagePathGreen' => Constants::IMAGE_PATH_DEV_GREEN,
        'imagePathYear' => Constants::IMAGE_PATH_DEV_YEAR,
    ));
}
```

and this is how I redirected from the "database route":

`return $this->redirectToRoute('appTourOverview', array(), 301);` but this gets cached and the database entries are never created...

### I tried:

I copied everything from the "display route" and let it return the database stuff immediately.

```
/* Get Network for User */
    $network = $this->getUser()->getNetwork()->getId();

    $tours = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Tour')->toursTodayByNetwork($network);

    return $this->render(':checker:index.html.twig', array(
        'tour' => $tours,
        'imagePath' => Constants::IMAGE_PATH_DEV,
        'imagePathGreen' => Constants::IMAGE_PATH_DEV_GREEN,
        'imagePathYear' => Constants::IMAGE_PATH_DEV_YEAR,
    ));
```

instead of the redirect. Unfortunately this only works after a refresh? (`$tours` is empty the first time)

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have enabled the HTTP Cache for example? Or do you use other caches?

Comment: Try to remove the parameter and status code for the redirect. The default status code is 302 and its possible that the code trigger some events. 

`return $this->redirectToRoute('appTourOverview');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `301` redirect means he page was moved permanently and this information will be cached in your browser now. Please change that parameter to `302` or just remove (this is not necessary). Then, unfortunately you need to remove your browser's cache and the it should work.

`302` means the redirect is temporary and browser won't cache it;

Comment: I see, but it is not really "temporary" as it's expected behaviour? I used this now http://stackoverflow.com/a/16753260/1092632 but I think yours is good too, so thank you!

Comment: Temporary means - don't cache. nothing else :)