# Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache), when go back in IE 11 doesn't clear the fields

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a form that has 3 fields. Once you have submitted the form it then displays a thank you page.
When you go away from this page and then press back, some unexpected things happen :

In IE 9, there is a page expired page on the thank you page but when you go back to the form, it has cleared
In IE 11 the thank you page is running normally but when you go back to the form, the form has not cleared
When checking other browsers, it works perfectly, when going back the thank you page is fine and the form has been cleared.

I know you shouldn't really be going back after a form but just need it to be secure.

I just added the code in the page load method

```
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache)
```

How is the method expected to work in IE9 and IE 11?
Am I missing some code for it to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below and see weather it works or not.

```
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
```

Some related link

1. [Why both no-cache and no-store should be used in HTTP response?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/866822/why-both-no-cache-and-no-store-should-be-used-in-http-response)
2. [How to control web page caching, across all browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547/making-sure-a-web-page-is-not-cached-across-all-browsers/2068407#2068407)