# Would an onbeforeunload handler really stop my page caching?

Tags: javascript, caching, dom-events

In 2007 in a post called "[Mastering The Back Button With Javascript](http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Mastering_The_Back_Button_With_Javascript)"  Patrick Hunlock claimed that just including an `onbeforeunload` handler in a page will stop caching. (I guess browser caching.) He was very emphatic about it:

> Just having an unbeforeunload event handler -- regardless of whether or not it actually does anything, regardless of whether or not you spawn a dialog box or not, even if the entire function declaration consists entirely of just { } -- just **defining** an event handler will prevent the page from being cached -- ever.
>
> As a matter of fact, even if you allow page caching, the page will be
>   not be cached. **Having an onbeforeunload event means the page will be
>   re-built every single time it is accessed.** Javascripts will re-run,
>   server-side scripts will be re-run, the page will be built as if the
>   user was hitting it for the very first time, even if the user got to
>   the page just by hitting the back or forward button.

Funny thing is I can't find any mention anywhere else of this, apart from one or two people who refer to Hunlock's post. Can anyone clear up this question? Is it really true, or can I safely use that event?

Comment: I have no idea, but the lack of references/documentation makes me think it's no good. Even if it were fine to use, just don't. Use proper caching techniques to accomplish what you want

Comment: Thanks Ian - I'm not trying to mess with the caching, just want to know if there's a risk I'll break it.

Comment: There are a lot of google references to firefox and safari not using the cache when the back button is used to leave or return to a page, if there is an unload or onunloadhandler. Here is one- http://madhatted.com/2013/6/16/you-do-not-understand-browser-history

Comment: Thanks kennebec - very interesting reference there to a cache in FF and Safari which "stores the current state of the DOM in memory" for re-rending if you click the back button. It says an unload handler on the window will break that caching.

Comment: Not that it matters a great deal anymore, but IE6 would not store the page state either if the unload handler was used.  I don't know if IE7  or 8 is the same way.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy, any more info on this is useful! Presumably IE6 IE7 were the current versions when Patrick Hunlock wrote his post.

Comment: Hehe, I also bumped into that old "Mastering..." article today, and then I also wanted to do some fact-checking (exactly like in the question), and then Google just dropped me right here. :)

Comment: Shows up here too https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/beforeunload

Answer (score 0):

For archaeologists, this was documented as a feature [introduced in Firefox 1.5](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Firefox/Releases/1.5/Using_Firefox_1.5_caching).

Be careful not to confuse the cache with the browser history (also known as the store) - page elements could be included in both.  If the desired behavior is to force a browser to re-load an HTML page from the server if the Forward and Back navigation buttons are used (for example, because the page displays sensitive information, or content was changed using Javascript or Ajax calls) then `Cache-control no-store` should be used - or better use both `no-store` and `no-cache`.

Further reading:

- [Why both no-cache and no-store should be used in HTTP response?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/866822/why-both-no-cache-and-no-store-should-be-used-in-http-response)
- [OWASP: Testing for Browser cache weakness](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_Browser_cache_weakness_(OTG-AUTHN-006))